# Cannot download Android Studio at all on Windows 10

Tags: browser, internet, download, android-studio

When I try to download Android Studio off of the website (https://developer.android.com/studio) it fails, resulting in this error on Firefox:

[image: image id: a screenshot of an error message from firefox with multiple lines of text. title: "Secure Connection Failed." subtitle:"An error occurred during a connection to redirector.gvt1.com. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR" text: "Error code: PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR" bullet point text: "The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified." second bullet point text: "Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem." link text: "Learn more..." end image id.]

And this in Google Chrome:

[image: image id: a screenshot of an error message from google chrome with multiple lines of text. title: "This site can't be reached" text: "redirector.gvt1.com unexpectedly closed the connection. Try:" bullet point 1: "Checking the connection" bullet point 2: "Checking the proxy and the firewall" bullet point 3: "Running Windows Network Diagnostics" subtext: "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" end image id]

I have tried everything I can think of on my end short of calling someone over to take a look at it. I am new to coding and am not extremely good with computers in general, so there likely has been something I just haven't thought of.

Comment: Your title should state "Cannot download" not "Cannot install". It's not an accurate problem description, please keep that in mind. As for the issue, did you try on another machine/system? Are you using any kind of VPN/proxy?

Comment: you are not a developer, you don't want Android Studio. you want adb and fastboot that is available here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

Comment: Well the domain indicated in your screenshot isn’t the Android Studio website, so you must be connected to a proxy, which is redirecting you. So disable it. Contact your IT Administrator for assistance if you don’t know how to do that.

Comment: @Ramhound I was also suspicious of the URL, but apparently, it's [Google's redirection service](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/what-are-these-suspicious-google-gvt1com-urls/) including for Android-related executables.